# How to get user name, email, etc. from MobileServiceUser?

Tags: c#, wpf, azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-active-directory

After a lot of digging around I've got my WPF application signing users in via Azure Mobile Service. My Mobile Service is connected to an Azure Active Directory that I have set up. However, when I log the user in with MobileServiceClient.LoginAsync(...) the MobileServiceUser UserId is in an unreadable hash it seems. For example it looks like: "Aad:X3pvh6mmo2AgTyHdCA3Hwn6uBy91rXXXXXXXXXX". What exactly is this?

I'd like to grab the user's display name to use but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the userID of Azure Active Directory. You need to create a service to expose your AAD info through a service and retrieve the additional information using the access token you get from your user.

First:

```
    ServiceUser user = this.User as ServiceUser;
    var identities = await user.GetIdentitiesAsync();
    var aad = identities.OfType<AzureActiveDirectoryCredentials>().FirstOrDefault();
    var aadAccessToken = aad.AccessToken;
    var aadObjectId = aad.ObjectId;
```

This will give you the access token and objectID , then you need to query the information through AAD graphy API. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn151678.aspx
Look at the sample request part. You should provide the query with the access token you got and objectId.

Comment: I am getting Access Token missing or malformed when querying through graph API. any idea?

Comment: Probably need more details than what you have described here. It should work as long as you make sure your access token is present in your request header.

Comment: What is the "this" object in this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach, after reading http://justazure.com/azure-active-directory-part-2-building-web-applications-azure-ad/ scroll to the section on Identity in .Net it talks how claims are a standard part of the framework. So once you get the credentials object like provided by @beast

```
var aad = identities.OfType<AzureActiveDirectoryCredentials>().FirstOrDefault();
```

You can actually grab a dictionary with the various properties. Examples of some the properties can be found at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.claims.claimtypes(v=vs.110).aspx

So from there you can do the following:

```
if (aad != null)
{
    var d = aad.Claims;
    var email = d[ClaimTypes.Email];
}
```

I did this to pull the user id which was cross referenced in a table. FYI I am using App Service, but I believe the credentials object is the same in Mobile Service