# Windows Universal App Get username from Microsoft Account Authentication

Tags: c#, uwp, microsoft-account

So I wanted the users to login to my app using Microsoft Account
I did all the setup in my mobile service in Azure and this is how I implement the login in my App:

```
    private async Task<bool> AuthenticateAsync()
    {
        string message;
        bool success = false;
        try
        {
            user = await App.MobileService
             .LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount);
            message =
                string.Format("You are now signed in - {0}", user.UserId);

            success = true;
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            message = "You must log in. Login Required";
        }

        var dialog = new MessageDialog(message);
        dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("OK"));
        await dialog.ShowAsync();
        return success;
    }
```

all is working fine but all I get from this is a User Id.

and I need the name of the user that logged in, can anyone help me how should I go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and I need the name of the user that logged in, can anyone help me how should I go about this

For UWP app, this is impossible using official managed API. See `MobileServiceAuthentication` class in [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/sdk/Managed/src/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices/Authentication/MobileServiceAuthentication.cs#L137)

```
internal async Task<MobileServiceUser> LoginAsync()
{
        string response = await this.LoginAsyncOverride();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response))
        {
            JToken authToken = JToken.Parse(response);

            // Get the Mobile Services auth token and user data
            this.Client.CurrentUser = new MobileServiceUser((string)authToken["user"]["userId"]);
            this.Client.CurrentUser.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken = (string)authToken[LoginAsyncAuthenticationTokenKey];
        }

        return this.Client.CurrentUser;
}
```

The official sdk just retrieves the userId and MobileServiceAuthenticationToken, for other platform, we need to use `GetIdentitiesAsync()` method to get identity, see [How to get user name, email, etc. from MobileServiceUser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29884219/how-to-get-user-name-email-etc-from-mobileserviceuser/33621035) or [LINK](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5334b10a-0629-41fb-9233-da603afe181a)

The username info actually has been retrieved in the SSO process:
[image]

So you have to implement the auth process(Extend the method based on the open source code) and maintain the username information as you need.

If you can get the user's input, maybe you can also call Live API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn659736.aspx#Requesting_info

Comment: Thank you for a great detailed answer